# Is there a way to make a reference to a class object before I instantiate it?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to play around with Python making a simple text game. I have a `Room` class:

```
class Room():
    def __init__(self, monster, exits, loot):
        self.room_guard = monster
        self.exits = exits
        self.guard_is_alive = True
        self.loot = loot
```

When I am creating the rooms I am getting an error because I call them before they are created like so:

```
room_2 = Room(spider, {"West": room_3, "East": room_4, "South": room_1}, 2)
room_1 = Room(trogdor, {"North": room_2}, 2)
```

Room 2 can't have `"South": room_1` because it hasn't been instantiated. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two options: indirection, assignment after creation.

Rather than referring to the rooms directly use a `dict` that maps the names of the rooms to the rooms:

```
rooms = {}
rooms['room_2'] = Room(spider, {"West": 'room_3', "East": 'room_4', "South": 'room_1'}, 2)
rooms['room_1'] = Room(trogdor, {"North": 'room_2'}, 2)
```

Or assign the exits after the Room objects have been created:

```
room_2 = Room(spider, {}, 2)
room_1 = Room(trogdor, {}, 2)

room_2.exits = {"West": room_3, "East": room_4, "South": room_1}
room_1.exits = {"North": room_2}
```

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to refer to an object before it has been created. However, you can modify your `exits` dictionary after the object has been created to create links between your rooms. One nice way to do this might be to let the second room you create automatically create some links back to itself, via an additional parameter:

```
class Room():
    def __init__(self, monster, exits, loot, exits_back={}):
        self.room_guard = monster
        self.exits = exits
        self.guard_is_alive = True
        self.loot = loot
        for direction, room in exits_back.items():
            room.exits[direction] = self
```

Then you'd pass an extra dictionary to the contructor of the later room, letting it set the link back to itself from the previous room:

```
room_2 = Room(spider, {"West": room_3, "East": room_4}, 2)        # no room_1 ref here
room_1 = Room(trogdor, {"North": room_2}, 2, {"South": room_2})   # extra dict passed
```

Comment: Interesting. I am going to try this out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of solutions to this problem. Here is another one. This solution waits to initialize the object until after all of the objects have been created.

```
class Room():

    def create(self, monster, exits, loot=None):
        self.room_guard = monster
        self.exits = exits
        self.guard_is_alive = True
        self.loot = loot

room_1 = Room()
room_2 = Room()
room_3 = Room()
room_4 = Room()

room_1.create('spider', {"West": room_3, "East": room_4, "South": room_1}, 2)
room_2.create('trogdor', {"North": room_2}, 2)
```

---

**Edit:** Using the above method, here is one possible way of organizing your rooms. I've stored the rooms in a [2-dimensional list](http://www.learningpythonprogramming.com/2010/12/python-multi-dimensional-lists-jagged.html). This solution is nice because you don't have to worry about where the exits are; the program figures that out for you for each room that is created.

```
rooms = []
horizontal_room_count = 2
vertical_room_count = 2

class Room():

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def create(self, monster, loot):
        self.room_guard = monster
        self.exits = self.get_exits()
        self.guard_is_alive = True
        self.loot = loot

    def get_exits(self):
        x, y = self.x, self.y

        def get_room(x2, y2):
            if x2 < 0 or y2 < 0 or x2 >= horizontal_room_count or y2 >= vertical_room_count:
                return None
            return rooms[x2][y2]


        return {
                    'West': get_room(x-1, y), 
                    'East': get_room(x+1, y),
                    'North': get_room(x, y+1),
                    'South': get_room(x, y-1)
                }

rooms = [[Room(x,y) for x in range(horizontal_room_count)] for y in range(vertical_room_count)]

rooms[0][0].create('spider', loot=2)
rooms[0][1].create('trogdor', loot=2)
```

We know have a nice simple interface for interacting with rooms. Here is an example of using the interface to interact with the room in the corner position (0, 0).

```
#creating the room
>> rooms[0][0].create('evil_fairy', loot=3)

#finding the exits
>> rooms[0][0].exits

#accessing info
>> rooms[0][0].loot
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way I can imagine is to create the objects, then create the links in two distinct steps.

```
class Room(object):
    def __init__(self, monster, loot):
        self.exits = {direction:None for direction in
                      ["North", "South", "East", "West"]}
        # rooms have no exits until you add links to them manually
        self.room_guard = monster
        self.guard_is_alive = True
        self.loot = loot
    def add_link(self, other, ordinal):
        """Creates a link between this room and another in the specified direction

        room_A.add_link(room_B, 'East')
        sets room_A.exits['East'] = room_B and room_B.exits['West'] = room_A"""

        if not hasattr(other, 'exits')
            raise ValueError("Can only link with other objects with exits")
        ordinal_map = {"North":"South", "South":"North",
                       "East":"West", "West":"East"}
        try:
            other_ordinal = ordinal_map[ordinal]
        except KeyError:
            raise ValueError("ordinal must be one of {}".format(
                    ', '.join(ordinal_map.keys())))

        self.exits[ordinal] = other
        other.exits[other_ordinal] = self
```

First make the rooms

```
map = """  A - B   C
           |       |
           D - E - F """
# bonus points if you can build a function that takes this as input and
# outputs the correct structure of rooms!!!

rooms = {key:Room(*args) for key,args in zip("ABCDEF",monster_loot_tuples)}
# monster_loot_tuples would be a list like [("Gargoyle","+1 Sword of Smiting"), ...]
```

Then add the links

```
rooms['A'].add_link(rooms['B'], 'East')
rooms['A'].add_link(rooms['D'], 'South')
rooms['D'].add_link(rooms['E'], 'East')
rooms['E'].add_link(rooms['F'], 'East')
rooms['F'].add_link(rooms['C'], 'North')
```

Comment: of course `rooms` is probably better used as a list, unless you need to access them specifically by name later on.